# How to Unit test Angular Extend

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-mocha

I have a controller which is using angular extend. 
How can i test angular extend ?

```
angular.module('conditionmonitor').controller('mapController', ['$scope', '$http', 'UIConfig', function ($scope, $http, UIConfig) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: UIConfig.LATITUTE,
            lng: UIConfig.LONGITUDE,
            zoom: UIConfig.ZOOMLEVEL
        },
        markers: $scope.markers,
        layers: $scope.layers,
        defaults: {
            scrollWheelZoom: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't have to test angular.extend. Unit test purpose it to test your controller does, which in this case puts values to scope. So you should test that given a condition you should have expected values on scope. You can also take it out to a service if it make sense - and it can sometimes help your testings as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing Unit Tests you aren't meant to test the functionality of a 3rd party library, but only test the functionality that you are writing yourself.

The assumption is that the 3rd party library that you are using is indeed already tested ([which is true for angularjs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/test))